# Handling more than one callback parameter for content in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to send two different array from php to jQuery ? Trying to get the two different array from php into two different callback parameter capturing the content of the array in jQuery.

```js
$( document ).ready( function(){
  
  $.ajax({ 
      
       url : 'get.php',
    
       type : 'get',
       
       dataType : 'json'
  
    }).done( function( data1, data2 ){
     
     $( 'span:nth-last-child(2)' ).text(data1);
    
     $( 'span:nth-last-child(1)' ).text(data2);
    
    });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  
  <span></span>
  
  <span></span>
  
</div>
```

```
<?php

  $val1 = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];

  $val2 = [ "apple", "mango" , "orange" ];

  echo json_encode( $val1 );

  echo json_encode( $val2 );

?>
```

**Required Result**:

```
red,green,blue
apple,mango,orange
```

Comment: You return an array `echo json_encode( array($val1, $val2) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change get.php

```
<?php

  $data['val1'] = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];

  $data['val2'] = [ "apple", "mango" , "orange" ];

  echo json_encode( $data );

?>
```

change script

```
$( document ).ready( function(){

  $.ajax({ 

       url : 'get.php',

       type : 'get',

       dataType : 'json'

    }).done( function( data ){

     $( 'span:nth-last-child(2)' ).text(data.val1);

     $( 'span:nth-last-child(1)' ).text(data.val2);

    });

  });
```

Comment: @YSuraj: provided answer

Answer (score 2):

It is better to add the two arrays into one array of arrays, then send it back as `json` encoded string, which can be decoded later from jQuery:

```
<?php 
$arr = [0=>$val1, 1=>$val2];
//Send encoded string to client
echo json_encode($arr);
//This will produce something like: [["red","green","blue"],["apple","mango","orange"]]
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

  $val1 = [ "red", "green", "blue" ];

  $val2 = [ "apple", "mango" , "orange" ];

  echo json_encode(['val1'=>$val1,'val2'=>$val2]);

?>
```

and then in jquery

```
.done( function(response){
     var res = json_decode(response);
     $( 'span:nth-last-child(2)' ).text(res.val1);

     $( 'span:nth-last-child(1)' ).text(res.val2);

    });
```